# Symfony2 Date transforming (dd.mm.yyyy) to (yyyy-mm-dd)

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, date, datetime

I'm new with **Symfony2** and **PHP** and I've a question pertaining to formatting dates.

I have a form where the user can enter a date in this format: `dd.mm.yyyy`. The SQL Database uses this format: `yyyy-mm-dd`. Now when make an sql query i get a mismatch of course.

```
public function getFindingPatientQuery($birthdate){
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT p
            FROM Data\LiveBundle\Entity\DataAPatient p
            WHERE p.pDateOfBirth = :birthdate'
        )->setParameter('birthdate', $birthdate| ('Y-m-d'));

    return $query;
}
```

What's the easiest way to transform the input `dd.mm.yyyy` date to the demanded format `yyyy-mm-dd`? Does there exist some global solution if I'd need this transformation more than 1 time? I prefer a non-JavaScript solution.

I found some answer here in the forum but nothing worked.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before you write anything more here, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also, this question is too broad. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to indicate parameter type and make sure the `$birthdate` variable is a `\DateTime` object:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
...
->setParameter('birthdate', $birthdate, Type::DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your birthdate isn't the type date ?

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', $birthdate);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```